# what should be the dimension of image in Convolutional neural network

Tags: image-processing, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

Beginner to Deep learning..

I'm trying to identify the slum using satellite images(google map) for Pune city. So, in training dataset i have provided about 100 images of slum and 100 images of other area. But my model is not able to classify input image properly even though accuracy rate is high.
I think this might be because of dimensions of image. 
I'm resizing all images to 128*128 pixel.
Kernal size is 3*3.

Link to the map:
https://www.google.co.in/maps/@18.5129661,73.822531,286m/data=!3m1!1e3?hl=en

Following is the code

```python
import os,cv2
import glob
import numpy as np
from keras.utils import plot_model
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense, Dropout


PATH = os.getcwd()
data_path = PATH + '/dataset/*'


files = glob.glob(data_path)
X = []

for myFiles in files:
 image = cv2.imread(myFiles)
 image_resize = cv2.resize(image, (256, 256))
 X.append(image_resize)

image_data = np.array(X)
image_data = image_data.astype('float32')
image_data /= 255
print("Image_data shape ", image_data.shape)


no_of_classes = 2
no_of_samples = image_data.shape[0]
label = np.ones(no_of_samples, dtype='int64')

label[0:86] = 0     #Slum
label[87:] = 1    #noSlum

Y = to_categorical(label, no_of_classes)


#shuffle dataset

x,y = shuffle(image_data , Y, random_state = 2)

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state = 2)

#print(x_train)
#print(y_train)


input_shape = image_data[0].shape

input = Input(input_shape)

conv_1 = Convolution2D(32,(3,3), padding='same', activation='relu')(input)
conv_2 = Convolution2D(32,(3,3), padding = 'same', activation = 'relu')(conv_1)
pool_1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2))(conv_2)
drop_1 = Dropout(0.5)(pool_1)

conv_3 = Convolution2D(64,(3,3), padding='same', activation='relu')(drop_1)
conv_4 = Convolution2D(64,(3,3), padding='same', activation = 'relu')(conv_3)
pool_2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2))(conv_4)
drop_2 = Dropout(0.5)(pool_2)

flat_1 = Flatten()(drop_2)
hidden = Dense(64,activation='relu')(flat_1)
drop_3 = Dropout(0.5)(hidden)
out = Dense(no_of_classes,activation = 'softmax')(drop_3)

model = Model(inputs = input, outputs = out)

model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'rmsprop',  metrics= ['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train,y_train,batch_size=10,nb_epoch=20,verbose =1, validation_data=(x_test,y_test))

model.save('model.h5')

score = model.evaluate(x_test,y_test,verbose=1)
print('Test Loss: ',score[0])
print('Test Accuracy: ',score[1])


test_image = x_test[0:1]
print(test_image.shape)

print (model.predict(test_image))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, the behavior you've described above resembles to the inability of NN  to identify small objects on input images. Just imagine you give an image of 128*128 with rough noise where nothing is seen - you want NN to correctly classify objects?

What to do? 
1) Try to manually convert some input image from your dataset to 128*128 size and see on what data you truly train your NN. So, it'll give you more insight --> maybe you need to have better image's dimension size

2) Add more Conv layers with more neurons that will give you ability to detect small and more sophisticated objects by adding more non-linearity to your output function. Google such great Neural Network structures as ResNet.

3) Add more training data, 100 images isn't enough to have an appropriate result

4) Add data augmentation technique as well ( Rotations seem so strong in your case )

And don't give up :) Eventually, you'll solve it out. Good Luck

Comment: I'll try these suggestions. Looks like it is going to take some serious elbow grease.. Thank u so much..!

Comment: You're welcome.  Waiting for your success and achievements. Edit your post with additional facts, it's definitely going to help.

Comment: You were right.. I realized that it was difficult  for machine to detect features in 128*128 dimension. Increasing the dimension of image's and adding more training data worked for me. But accuracy is not very good. I guess adding more images to dataset and augmentation should work.

Comment: Good to know) When you get more data and data augmentation is added, I'm sure you'll succeed :) P.S I usually use 512*512 dimensions or around it. as well as 1 batch size and GPU on AWS. But it so depends on data, maybe some dog&cat classification 128*128 is totally great. Usually, manually checking how image looks when you decrease&increase dimensions using opencv library is the key to understand